# UILabel! Is appearing instead of hiding in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to have my label appear off of the screen before the game is won. When the game is won I want the label to appear on the screen. I am using the `UIView.animateWithDuration` and `viewDidAppear` methods. I'm thinking it has something to do with `viewDidAppear`.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //All the odd numbers will be noughts & even will be crosses
    var goNumber = 1
    var winner = 0

    //0 = empty, 1 = nought, 2 = cross
    var gameState = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

    let winningCombinations = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]]

    @IBOutlet weak var button0: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var winnerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        var image = UIImage()

        if gameState[sender.tag] == 0 {
            println(sender.tag)

            if goNumber % 2 == 0 {
                image = UIImage(named: "cross.png")!
                gameState[sender.tag] = 2
            } else {
                image = UIImage(named: "nought.png")!
                gameState[sender.tag] = 1
            }

            for combination in winningCombinations {
                if (gameState[combination[0]] == gameState[combination[1]] && gameState[combination[1]] == gameState[combination[2]]) && gameState[combination[0]] != 0 {
                    winner = gameState[combination[0]]
                }
            }

            if winner != 0 {
                println("We have a winner")

                label.text = (winner == 1) ? "Noughts has won" : "Crosses has won"

                UIView.animateWithDuration(1) {
                    self.label.center = CGPointMake(self.label.center.x + 400, self.label.center.y)
                }
            }

            goNumber++
            sender.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        label.center = CGPointMake(label.center.x - 400, label.center.y)
    }
}
```

Comment: set it hidden initially and unhide later on when you need. then do that animation of sliding in or animate the unhide.

Comment: With the `.hidden` method, correct?

Comment: use  youlbalel.hidden = true inside viewDidLoad(). Then when you need to show on the animation block do yourlabel.hidden = false and then animate

Answer (score 0):

try this,

**Swift 2**

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 0, options: CurveEaseOut, animations: {

    self.label.center = CGPointMake(self.label.center.x + 400, self.label.center.y)

}, completion : nil)
```

**Swift 3, 4, 5**

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

    self.label.center = CGPoint(x: self.label.center.x + 400, y: self.label.center.y)

}, completion : nil)
```

Comment: Or Try viewWillAppear instead of viewDidAppear

Answer (score -1):

Change your `viewDidLoad` to look like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.label.hidden = true
}
```

And change your `if winner != 0` to look like this:

```
if winner != 0 {
    // add this expression:
    self.label.hidden = false

    println("We have a winner")
    //...
}
```